# Help with probability problem: at least k draws of n balls Pr = 2/3?

Tags: probability

I am looking at question [2(b)](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/assignments/ps2sol.pdf) (not that I actually take this course). I can see why the answer makes sense, however, my first attempt was to reason that since

- each draw has $Pr(X) = 1/9$,
- it's "with replacement",
- each draw is independent

then we want to find the event $X_1 \cup X_2 \cup ... X_k = 1 $. So my initial answer $\sum_{i=1}^k{\frac{1}{9}} = 2/3$, for $k=6$ is incorrect, but I don't see why. What is wrong with my reasoning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a union is not necessarily the sum of the probabilities. If the events $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_k$ are **pairwise disjoint**, then indeed 
$$\Pr(X_1\cup X_2\cup\cdots\cup X_k)=\Pr(X_1)+\Pr(X_2)+\cdots+\Pr(X_k).\tag{$1$}$$
(The $X_i$ are pairwise disjoint if $X_i\cap X_j=\emptyset$ whenever $i\ne j$.)

But if the $X_i$ are not pairwise disjoint, the equality $(1)$ need not hold.

The $X_i$ in your post are **not** pairwise disjoint. They are *independent*, but that's an entirely different thing. In fact, except in trivial cases, independent events are not pairwise disjoint.

For example the events "blue on the third" and "blue on the fifth" are not disjoint. It is perfectly possible that both happen. If we assume that the probability of blue is exactly $0.10$, then the probability of blue on third and blue on fifth is $(0.10)^2$.

To see informally that your procedure cannot be right, imagine that we pick a ball $14$ times. Your calculation would give the probability of at least one blue as $(0.10)(14)=1.4$. But no probability can be greater than $1$.